# drupal hook_node_delete do nothing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook, drupal-hooks

I try to use the "hook" -> hook_delete_node in Drupal 7.

```
function mymodule_node_delete($node) {
  var_dump($node);
  exit;
}
```

But nothing.
In return, my hook_node_insert is ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you try to delete a node to invoke that hook?

Comment: Cleared the cache after adding your function? Your module actual name really is "mymodule", right?

Comment: **Cleared the cache** -> This is the answer ! thanx you @MilanG